# poetry install fails with [CalledProcessError] while installing github submodule

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-poetry

I'm new to python and github. when I'm trying to install few submodules getting below error.

- I'm using git bash on windows
- pip is at latest version 20.2.3.
- able to install other submodules using poetry successfully

```
    $ poetry install -vvv
    Using virtualenv: E:\Dev\venv\venv_test
    Installing dependencies from lock file
    
    [CalledProcessError]
    Command '['C:\\Users\\88810\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tziwqwewd56\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 3221226505.
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.6\clikit\console_application.py", line 131, in run
        status_code = command.handle(parsed_args, io)
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.6\clikit\api\command\command.py", line 120, in handle
        status_code = self._do_handle(args, io)
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.6\clikit\api\command\command.py", line 171, in _do_handle
        return getattr(handler, handler_method)(args, io, self)
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.6\cleo\commands\command.py", line 92, in wrap_handle
        return self.handle()
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\console\commands\install.py", line 69, in handle
        return_code = installer.run()
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\installation\installer.py", line 74, in run
        self._do_install(local_repo)
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\installation\installer.py", line 225, in _do_install
        ops = solver.solve(use_latest=whitelist)
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\puzzle\solver.py", line 36, in solve
        packages, depths = self._solve(use_latest=use_latest)
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\puzzle\solver.py", line 181, in _solve
        self._package, self._provider, locked=locked, use_latest=use_latest
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\mixology\__init__.py", line 7, in resolve_version
        return solver.solve()
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\mixology\version_solver.py", line 80, in solve
        next = self._choose_package_version()
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\mixology\version_solver.py", line 388, in _choose_package_version
        version = self._provider.complete_package(version)
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\puzzle\provider.py", line 601, in complete_package
        self.search_for_vcs(r)
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\puzzle\provider.py", line 175, in search_for_vcs
        name=dependency.name,
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\puzzle\provider.py", line 213, in get_package_from_vcs
        package = cls.get_package_from_directory(tmp_dir, name=name)
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\puzzle\provider.py", line 361, in get_package_from_directory
        cls._execute_setup()
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\puzzle\provider.py", line 872, in _execute_setup
        EnvManager.build_venv(tmp_dir)
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\utils\env.py", line 688, in build_venv
        builder.create(str(path))
      File "E:\python36\lib\venv\__init__.py", line 67, in create
        self._setup_pip(context)
      File "E:\python36\lib\venv\__init__.py", line 245, in _setup_pip
        subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
      File "E:\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "C:\Users\88810\.poetry\lib\poetry\utils\_compat.py", line 206, in run
        retcode, process.args, output=stdout, stderr=stderr
    
    (venv_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue after following these steps:

1. Upgraded python 3.6 to 3.7.4.
2. I had earlier installed python on E drive, installed it on C drive.